# How do I create new command line flags in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I have files saved into a "file1.ors" format. In this case, they are similar to dictionary entries. I have been tasked with now converting them to other formats, such as HTML, Bibtext, or JSON. However, my supervisor wants me to use python from the command line, and he wants the choice to be decided with new command-line flags. For example,

```
$ orsconvert.py --json file1.ors
```

which would take file1.ors and convert it into a JSON format. The issue is that I cannot even find anything on how to create/define my own command line flags that I can use with the program. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Python already has this built in its standard library: [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use library [argparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), this lib comes pre-installed with Python and very userful for creating command line options. Also, will provide a leverage to use `-h` command to get all the necessay help (check the first example in the doc).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the built-in `argparse` library — which in my experience is rather weird to use, especially when you want to implement a complex command line interface —, you might also want to look into [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) which uses Python's new type annotations feature and is somewhat easier to grasp.